# Extraer un valor de un input que esta dentro de un foreach con javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo unos datos que traigo de un foreach y los muestro en una tabla, y cada registro tiene un campo llamado cantidad, lo que pasa es que ese campo cuando lo envío por medio de javascript me toma el primer valor del primer registro los que le siguen me lo toma como si fuera el primero.

Este es el listado de registro traídos por el `foreach`:

```
<?php foreach ($articulos as $articulo): ?>

                <tr>     
                    <td><?= $this->Number->format($articulo->idart) ?></td>
                    <td><?= h($codigo = $articulo->codigo_orion)?></td>
                    <td><?= h($nombre = $articulo->nombre)?></td>

                     <?php if($articulo->tipo_item_id == 1){
                     echo '<td>ELECTRICA</td>';    
                         }elseif($articulo->tipo_item_id == 2){
                     echo '<td>ELECTRONICA</td>';    
                         }elseif($articulo->tipo_item_id == 3){
                     echo '<td>FERRETERIA</td>';    
                         }elseif($articulo->tipo_item_id == 4){
                     echo '<td>INSTRUMENTACIÓN</td>';   
                         }elseif($articulo->tipo_item_id == 5){
                     echo '<td>COMUN Y REDES</td>';    
                         }elseif($articulo->tipo_item_id == 6){
                     echo '<td>SALUD Y ALTURAS</td>';    
                         }elseif($articulo->tipo_item_id == 7){
                     echo '<td>PAPELERÍA</td>';    
                         }else{
                     echo '<td>PENDIENTE.</td>';
                         }
                    ?>
                    <td><?= $this->Number->format($articulo->valor_u)?></td>
                    <td><?= $this->Html->link(__(''), ['controller'=>'Articulos','action' => 'view', $articulo->idart], array('class' => 'teal-text text-darken-1 fa fa-eye fa-lg')) ?>&nbsp;</td> 
                    <td><input  type="text" name="cant[]" class='validate' style='text-align:center' placeholder="Ejemplo: 1" id="cantidad" required/></td>
                    <td><button class="btn waves-effect waves-light teal fa fa-shopping-cart" refid="<?php echo $articulo->idart; ?>" onClick="getAjax(this)" ></button></td>

                  </tr>


              <?php  endforeach;  ?>
```

Este es el que recibí por medio de `javascript`:

```
<script>
     function getAjax(object){


     var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;

       alert(cantidad);     

     var id = object.getAttribute("refid"); 


     }
</script>
```

Cuando ejecuto el alert para ver que valor me envía me muestra que solo toma el primer valor, cuando envío otro registro toma la primer cantidad del primer registro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo te suguiero las siguientes modificaciones:

- Agregar el `ID` del articulo (`idart`) al `id` del `input`
- En la función `getAjax`, agregar un segundo parámetro que sea el `ID` del articulo.

El código podría ser el siguiente:

```
<?php foreach ($articulos as $articulo): ?>
<tr>     
    <td><?= $this->Number->format($articulo->idart) ?></td>
    <td><?= h($codigo = $articulo->codigo_orion)?></td>
    <td><?= h($nombre = $articulo->nombre)?></td>
    <td><?php
    if ($articulo->tipo_item_id == 1) {
        echo 'ELECTRICA';
    } elseif ($articulo->tipo_item_id == 2) {
        echo 'ELECTRONICA';
    } elseif ($articulo->tipo_item_id == 3) {
        echo 'FERRETERIA';
    } elseif ($articulo->tipo_item_id == 4) {
        echo 'INSTRUMENTACIÓN';
    } elseif ($articulo->tipo_item_id == 5) {
        echo 'COMUN Y REDES';
    } elseif ($articulo->tipo_item_id == 6) {
        echo 'SALUD Y ALTURAS';
    } elseif ($articulo->tipo_item_id == 7) {
        echo 'PAPELERÍA';
    } else {
        echo 'PENDIENTE.';
    }
    ?></td>
    <td><?= $this->Number->format($articulo->valor_u)?></td>
    <td><?= $this->Html->link(__(''), ['controller'=>'Articulos', 'action' => 'view', $articulo->idart], array('class' => 'teal-text text-darken-1 fa fa-eye fa-lg')) ?>&nbsp;</td> 
    <!-- AQUI: El id del input tiene concatenado el idart -->
    <td><input type="text" name="cant[]" class='validate' style='text-align:center' placeholder="Ejemplo: 1" id="cantidad<?php echo $articulo->idart; ?>" required/></td>
    <!-- AQUI: Pasamos el idart como segundo parametro -->
    <td><button class="btn waves-effect waves-light teal fa fa-shopping-cart" onClick="getAjax(this, '<?php echo $articulo->idart; ?>')" ></button></td>
</tr>
<?php  endforeach;  ?>
```

Y el `javascript`:

```
<script>
function getAjax(object, idart){
   var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad" + idart).value;
   alert(cantidad);
   // Mas codigo
}
</script>
```

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, en la practica es mas ordenado y te permite manipular eventos 'uno a uno'

Answer (score 1):

Eso es por que todos los elementos tienen el mismo id, tendrias que obtener la lista de elementos e iterarlos con:

```
document.getElementsByName("cant[]");
document.querySelectorAll("#cantidad");
```

Alternativamente, podrias agregarle un atributo con el indice en el ciclo de php y usarlo como parte del selector:

```
document.querySelector("#cantidad[data-index=1]");
```

Comment: no mira que no me sirve porque necesito  traer el value  de el campo cantidad y ya iterado en el foreach

Comment: Entonces utiliza un indice como explique en el segundo ejemplo.